# Перекинуть данные в JUnit

Tags: java, selenium, юнит-тесты, junit, jframe

Создал тест в selenium. Экспортировал его в Java (JUnit). Тест запускается, все хорошо. Но там прописаны статические данные. Мне нужно забивать данные из вне(например из JFrame). По сути в тестах нельзя создать такое, потому что это как 2 разные сущности. Но может быть есть решение? Мне вообще надо на сайте забивать данные и чтобы эти данные прокидывались в JUnit. Как лучше всего сделать? С сайта я не смог прокинуть данные в JUnit и решил попробовать через JFrame. Но и тут столкнулся с проблемами. Как мне лучше всего сделать?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы данные для теста во время исполнение этого теста задавались через какой-то веб-интерфейс?

Comment: @AlexeyR. В идеале хочу так. Чтобы, например, я забил ФИО в своей форме (веб-интерфейс или что-то другое) и вот эти данные передались в тест, а он уже эти данные напечатал в другой форме на другом сайте. Сначала забиваю данные, а потом уже запускаю тест. Ну или во время теста это все сделать. Как лучше, как можно, пока что не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать для этого UI во время выполнения тестов плохо. Как тогда такие тесты запускать полностью автоматически на CI?

Обычно для этого используют параметризованные тесты, а данные удобно задавать либо в самом тесте в виде списка, грубо говоря, либо во внешнем файле, например, csv.

В junit5 с параметрами из файла это выглядит так:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(
    resources = "/data.csv", // файл должен лежать в classpath
    numLinesToSkip = 1 // это чтобы пропустить заголовок
)
void testMyFunction(
  String username, String password, String success) {
    // ...
}
```

Файл `data.csv` может выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
user,password,success
ok_user,ok_password,True
ok_user,invalid_password,False
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление, попробую.